# How can use setstate in Yii

Tags: php, yii, setstate

I want create random session after successful sign in and destroy it after log out.
How can do it? I used $this->user->setState
I added this code

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity {
    protected $_id;
    public function authenticate(){
        $user = User::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?', array(strtolower($this->username)));
        if(($user===null) || ($this->password!==$user->password)) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        } else {
            $this->_id = $user->id;
            $this->username = $user->username;
            $this->user->setState('random',Yii::app()->user->random);
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
       return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you giving values to Yii::app()->user->random ?

Comment: Even if I write $this->user->setState('random','value'); it not work

Comment: use `$this->setState` instead of `$this->user->setState`

Comment: Thank You! What is true? $this->setState or Yii::app()->user->

Comment: Yii::app()->user is an instance of UserIdentity, you should use it on the rest of the code. Here you use $this because you're settings the state for the current logged user.

Comment: Pleanse answer your own question so it can be closed.

Comment: Thank You! How do you think, may be better to use Yii :: app () -> session-> getSessionID (); it is random character and change after logout. Is it true? or better and safer create session with setState.

Answer (score 0):

Use $this->setState instead of $this->user->setState